# ng-show comparing with a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

given following example

```
    <div class="progress-animation" ng-show="file.state == STATES.DOWNLOADING">
        <div class="loader">Loading...</div>
    </div>
```

in javascript I've all these constants defined at a global level initialized before angular kicks in.

```
STATES = {
     DOWNLOADING: 1,
     UPDATING: 2,
     INSTALLING: 3
}
```

it works with `file.state == 1` but wondering how angular can evaluate it as an expression.

Comment: Angular expressions only work with scope-exposed variables or with primitives - it would not work with a globally-defined object

Comment: $scope.STATES should do the trick

Comment: @NewDev same applies for ng-class too?

Comment: @user2727195, yes - any expression.

Comment: @RobinHellemans thanks, it worked, you can post as answer

Comment: Ok I will, happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the value to `$rootScope` - seems to be one of few cases where it would be acceptable - to make it work app-wide:

```
var STATES = {...}

app.run(function($rootScope){
   $rootScope.STATES = STATES;
})
```

Comment: good suggestion, question, where to put this code if one is manually bootstrapping... `angular.bootstrap`

Comment: `.run`-registered functions run on bootstrap, so... doesn't where you put, so long as it runs before you bootstrap

Comment: is $rootScope minified safe? please add magnification safe version in case

Comment: Minification of `.run` - as is with any other injectable - is done the same way everywhere. I don't think diluting an answer with other concepts makes sense here. But to unblock you, the example above can be written like so: `.run(["$rootScope", function($rootScope){...}])` to be minification-safe

Answer (score 1):

Use `$scope.STATES` to expose `STATES` to your view, this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

if you defined in your controller

```
$scope.STATES = STATES;
```

your binding should work.  good luck!